# Inconsistent behaviour of HTML 5 video across desktop browsers

Tags: html, apache, video, cross-browser, html5-video

Someone I know has asked that I convert the videos on his webpage from using FlowPlayer to using native HTML 5 video.

To start off, I read that 3 formats are sufficient to cover the main desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera). Starting from `.avi`, I used Miro Video Converter to get videos in `.mp4`, `.ogg` and `.webm` as can be seen here:

[image]

To further help with cross-compatibility, I decided to use [VideoJS](http://videojs.com).

The mark up seemed straightforward too:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
       controls preload="auto" width="500px" height="300px"
       poster="something.png">
   <source src="something.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="something.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="something.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Here was what I found on the browsers (latest versions of all):

- **Google Chrome v30.0**: no problems whatsoever. It picked `.mp4` which was the highest quality of the three formats. Great.
- **Opera v12.16**: again, and a little surprisingly, no problems. Same behaviour as Chrome.
- **IE 11**: It's all downhill from here. IE 11 waits for the entire video to finish buffering and then starts playing **only audio**. So it was audio + the poster.
- **Firefox v24.0**: Unlike IE, it doesn't wait for the entire video to buffer but like IE, it plays only **audio and no video**. I read somewhere that Firefox does indeed support `.mp4` playback as long is it is a Windows 7 or higher OS. I am using Windows 8.

I then did some reading up on Apache. The headers stated that Firefox and IE were both recognizing the `mp4` as just that as opposed to some other MIME type. Even so, I added the following to my `.htaccess`:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

That didn't make a difference.

I then swapped the order of the `source` tags so that the `.ogv` video came first. Now, the video played in Firefox too but the `.ogv` is not nearly as high quality as the `.mp4`.

The page in question is this: http://keyrecords.com/Artist%20Pages/haggard.html

*I am linking to the page above for illustration purposes only. On the page above, `.ogv` comes first, so yes, I know it plays in Firefox.*

**So my question is this: what do I need to do to get Firefox and IE 10/11 to play the `.mp4`? It is safe to assume that these are the latest version of each of the browsers running Windows 7/8 machines.**

---

***EDIT: MediaInfo gave me this information about the file (does it look right?):***

[image]

Comment: Works for me in ff24 on win8

Comment: Yes, it does. Because it is using `.ogv`. As stated in the question, I want Firefox to play the `.mp4`.

Comment: I set up a test page on my server with an MP4 file. It works fine in FF24, Chrome 30, IE10 with Windows 7.

Comment: Can you try with this `mp4`: http://keyrecords.com/Artist%20Pages/Artist/haggard/left.mp4 ? Perhaps the problem is with the `mp4`...

Comment: Downloaded your MP4 to my test server - same problems with FF24 as you report. Tried a couple of MP4 clips from [this site](http://gallery.mobile9.com/c/mp4-videos/1/) (because they're free!) and had no problems at all. I'm not sufficiently up on video formats to make any suggestions as to what's wrong. I hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference, but is your Apache `AllowOverride` configuration allowing `AddType` in `.htaccess`?

Comment: How are you compressing the videos?  MP4 is just a container for the actual video and audio streams (which should be H.264 and AAC, respectively).  It looks like that left.mp4 was just compressed with black box for the video the whole way through.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I have edited the question by adding information about the files using MediaInfo: http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net

Comment: Does that information look right for the video to be able to play in Firefox and IE?

Comment: Looks like you got it working with HandBrake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using the [HandBrake converter](http://handbrake.fr).

I gave it the existing `.mp4` and asked it to give me a new `.mp4` with the following specs:

[image]
[image]

This new `.mp4` works in all 4 browsers without issues :)

Something about the way Miro Video converter converted the files caused IE and Firefox to see the audio track only but not the video track. This was rectified by reconverting using [HandBrake converter](http://handbrake.fr).